# Finding repeating data from data base

Tags: excel, vba

I have slight problem with my code. I have code that extracts data from a DB and puts it into a table. Example:

[image: Example Data]

I want the cells in L column to be highlighted (red for example) if the data is repeating itself for 3 shifts. Or if that can't be done, at least some way I could easily see when data is being repeated.

The idea is that I extract data that is out of a specific range.

---

SQL Code:

```
sql = "SELECT ID, (SELECT Number FROM WindingStands WHERE ID = TexMeasurements.WindingStandID) as Place, SpindleNumber, " _
    & "(SELECT Number FROM Assortments WHERE ID = TexMeasurements.AssortmentID) as Sifrs, " _
    & "(SELECT Name FROM Assortments WHERE ID = TexMeasurements.AssortmentID) as Sort, CreationTime, TexPV, TexSP " _
    & " FROM TexMeasurements " _
    & " WHERE CreationTime > " & fromdate & " AND CreationTime <= " & ToDate & " " _
    & " AND (TexLimit <= -3 OR TexLimit >= 3) ORDER BY Place, SpindleNumber, CreationTime"
```

---

I use code to view the data for each day like so:

```
Sub LastShift()
If (Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Value - Sheets(1).Cells(1, 2).Value) > 0.75 Then
    Sheets(1).Cells(2, 6).Value = Sheets(1).Cells(1, 2).Value + 0.75
    Sheets(1).Cells(2, 3).Value = Sheets(1).Cells(2, 6).Value - 0.5
End If
If (Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Value - Sheets(1).Cells(1, 2).Value) < 0.25 Then
    Sheets(1).Cells(2, 6).Value = Sheets(1).Cells(1, 2).Value - 0.25
    Sheets(1).Cells(2, 3).Value = Sheets(1).Cells(2, 6).Value - 0.5
End If
If (Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Value - Sheets(1).Cells(1, 2).Value) > 0.25 And (Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Value - Sheets(1).Cells(1, 2).Value) < 0.75 Then
    Sheets(1).Cells(2, 6).Value = Sheets(1).Cells(1, 2).Value + 0.25
    Sheets(1).Cells(2, 3).Value = Sheets(1).Cells(2, 6).Value - 0.5
End If
Call ExtractData

Sub ThisShift()
If (Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Value - Sheets(1).Cells(1, 2).Value) > 0.25 And (Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Value - Sheets(1).Cells(1, 2).Value) < 0.75 Then
    Sheets(1).Cells(2, 6).Value = Sheets(1).Cells(1, 2).Value + 0.75
    Sheets(1).Cells(2, 3).Value = Sheets(1).Cells(1, 2).Value + 0.25
End If
If (Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Value - Sheets(1).Cells(1, 2).Value) < 0.25 Then
    Sheets(1).Cells(2, 6).Value = Sheets(1).Cells(1, 2).Value + 0.25
    Sheets(1).Cells(2, 3).Value = Sheets(1).Cells(2, 6).Value - 0.5
End If
If (Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Value - Sheets(1).Cells(1, 2).Value) > 0.75 Then
    Sheets(1).Cells(2, 6).Value = Sheets(1).Cells(1, 2).Value + 1.25
    Sheets(1).Cells(2, 3).Value = Sheets(1).Cells(2, 6).Value - 0.5
End If
Call ExtractData
```

Answer (score 0):

In column `K`, you can put a formula, like this one:

```
=IF(AND(MATCH(J4;J3;0);MATCH(J4;J2;0));1;0)
```

In case cell values J3 and J4 are equal and J2 and J4 are equal, you see 1, otherwise you see `#N/A` (instead of zero, sorry). You can obviously also work with the the `Exact()` worksheet function.

Comment: Thank you for response. I guess i didn't wrote clear enough. You see the easiest way to compare data would be with data from cells C and D (C- work station, D- equipment on this work station). And i need that program marks L5 because today (15.09.2018 from 6-18 and 14.09.2018 from 18-6 and 14.09.2018 6-18 has same entry - 103 (place, workstation) and 3 (nr. of equipment)